How to change font family of button and text input in React Native Paper?
I've just started using React Native Paper and I've gone through the documentation but I'm not able to see how I can change font family of button and text input. I'm also not able to find anything online. Could you please help me.
I'm able to change the font color in Button using the prop textColor. But I can't find any prop for font family.
<Button
          style={{
            width: "90%",
            height: 46,
            justifyContent: "center",
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
          textColor="#FFFFFF"
          buttonColor="#797c83"
        >

Similarly for text input, I'm able to change the color of both placeholder and text but can't find any option for font family.
<TextInput
            placeholder="Enter email"
            placeholderTextColor="#758195"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
            underlineColor="transparent"
            activeUnderlineColor="#758195"
            textColor="#FFF"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#041e29",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "#4A6171",
              width: "90%",
            }}
            left={<TextInput.Icon icon="email" />}
          />


So I just figured it out from a bunch of Github forums I searched.
For the button, we have to use the labelStyle prop to add a font family.
<Button labelStyle={{ fontFamily: "Fraunces_600SemiBold"}}>
      Log In
</Button>

For the text input, we have to use the contentStyle prop.
<TextInput contentStyle={{ fontFamily: "Alegreya_500Medium" }} />

